# How not to duplicate an SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create an online passenger manifest that a pilot fills in. So I use the statement

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE PassengerManifest(PilotName CHAR(30),Date DATE, FlightDuration INT, PRIMARY KEY(PilotName))";
```

But what happens when a second pilot tries to fill in the same form, he is met with the error:

Error creating table: Table 'PassengerManifest' already exists

So I though, fine, I will simply replace the SQL statement above with this statement:

```
$sql="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PassengerManifest(PilotName CHAR(30),Date DATE, FlightDuration INT, PRIMARY KEY(PilotName))";
```

But when I do that, I get the error:

Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...

All I am trying to do is to prevent the same table from being created everytime a pilot signs in. How can I do this, please?

Comment: You should not be creating a table for each pilot - create a table now and then insert into it for each pilot

Comment: So when a second pilot submits his form he wipes out all data from previous pilots... Is that how the app is supposed to work?? (And, nope, MySQL does not have a `CREATE OR REPLACE` statement for tables, only for views; just run *two* queries, you lazy man.)

Comment: If you're having trouble with application structure, a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) will give you a variety of tools for managing tables and changes made to them over time.

Answer (score 1):

step 1 : You should create one table for all pilots , in this table you have some columns might be below (you must define all pilot attributes in your table) :

```
CREATE TABLE pilot (
  id bigint(35) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name_pilot varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  family_pilot varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  email_pilot varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  pswd_pilot varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  phone_pilot varchar(40) NOT NULL
);
```

step 2 : for insert data you can use insert query in your script or other query executing ways

```
INSERT INTO pilot(name_pilot,family_pilot,email_pilot,pswd_pilot,phone_pilot) VALUES ('Alireza','Mirhabibi','mirhabibialireza@gmail.com','123456','009890000000');
```

and you can executing this query for each pilot similar to below:

```
INSERT INTO pilot(name_pilot,family_pilot,email_pilot,pswd_pilot,phone_pilot) VALUES ('pouriya','rezaie','test@gmail.com','656546468656554555554','00989111111');
```

Special Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the table datatypes and columns when you check if the table already exists.

The syntax you should be using is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PassengerManifest;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/drop-table.html

**Additional comment:**

I am unsure why you are dropping the table each time a pilot attempts to fill in the same form.  If you want multiple pilots to fill in this form you should be using an `INSERT` statement and `DELETE` if you need to remove an entry.

I would recommend creating and dropping tables as an administrative function, not an operation from a standard user, for example, a pilot.

Comment: Darren, much appreciated.